# How to get the span text using java script to pass it to GA through GTM

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I have my  piece of code like this on my website :

```
<span itemprop="productID" data-masterid="MV-20648-BR">20649-BR</span>
```

In which I need to get the 20649-BR

i have tried using this:

```
var div = document.getElementByClassName("itemprop");
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");
  alert(spans);
```

but I was not able to get the text value.
can anyone help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to interactive with Model Attribute in HTML5, You need create in 'Custom Javascript' Variable:

[From Variables > New > Dom Elemetn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtocM.png)

Name it, then add this code inside it:

```js
function(){
  
   var masterId = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-masterid]');
   var allmasterId = Array.prototype.map.call(masterId, function(a) { return  a.getAttribute('data-masterid');  });
    
   return allmasterId;
}
```

Now you can use this Variable name any where in GTM by {{varibale_name}}.

Comment: You do not event need custom HTML, the DOM variable type in GTM suppors css selectors and can return either the text node (default) or any attribute specified.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the content inside the span tag you can use this which will give you the text inside it

```html
 <span id="demo">asdriweognaerg</span>
    <script>
    var spantext=document.getElementById("demo");
    alert((spantext).textContent);
    </script>
```